# add model query into file_field_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

```
<%= file_field_tag :image2 ,"#{Setting.setting_image_value('image2')}" %>
```

how to set value into field_tag, it cannot be proceed and pop out undefined method `merge' for "":String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<%= file_field_tag :image2 , value: "#{Setting.setting_image_value('image2')}" %>
```

For more info:

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/file_field_tag